# NSUserDefaults saved data making it to the app store

Tags: iphone, app-store, nsuserdefaults

If I have some saving in NSUserDefaults whilst debugging my app, and then I submit it to the store, will the stuff be stored on that too? or does it get cleared when saved for a new distribution?

Cheers
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will be there, but the things that you saved will not package with the app.